# Растянуть DataGrid при изменение окна

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding ActivitiesUser, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

</Grid>
```

Так не получается растянуть, как можно, чтоб сам DataGrid и его Column тянулись на всю рабочую область?

Comment: Столбы все равно не на всю растягиваются, а по размеру данных

Comment: Так, если я явно буду указывать, то если окно будет менять размеры, то столбы же не будут менять размеры?

Comment: Да, подошло. Оформите ответ, выберу его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить свойство

```
ColumnWidth = "*"
```

---

[`ColumnWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columnwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) свойство, которое отвечает за установку значения ширины по умолчанию для каждого столбца.

О том, какие режимы можно задать для этого свойства можно подробнее прочитать [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridlength(v=vs.110).aspx).

Кроме этого `DataGrid` позволяет указывать ширину индивидуально для каждого столбца отдельно. Для этого нужно установить свойство `AutoGenerateColumns = false` и определить каждый столбец явно. Несмотря на то, что при таком способе затрачивается больше усилий он позволяет более точно настроить отображение.

Поэтому если вы точно знаете какое количество столбцов у вас должно быть рекомендуется использовать именно второй подход.